# Lync chat with multiple contacts from windows command line

Tags: lync

I can start a chat to a specified contact from command line like:

```
start sip:abc@abc.com
```

But when I want to chat to multiple contacts using command line like:

```
start im:<sip:a@abc.com><sip:b@abc.com>
```

A command syntax error will appear. I tried many ways but found no solution for this. How can I fix it? Thanks forwardly.

Answer (score 5):

Quotes fixed it for me. Like this:

```
start im:"<sip:a@abc.com><sip:b@abc.com>"
```